# VB.net - How can a definition at module level throw an exception

Tags: vb.net, scope

I was beginning to think that I was getting good at VB.net, but not this one has me stumped.

Code looks something like this

```
Public Class MyServer
 ..... 
 Public myMQTTclient = New MqttClient("www.myserv.com")
 .....

   Private Sub Ruptela_Server(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
     MyBase.Load
       <some code>
       StartMQTT()
       <some more code>
       MQTT_Publish(.....)
     End Sub

Public Function StartMQTT()
   ' Establish a connection 
    Dim code As Byte
    Try
        code = myMQTTclient.Connect(MQTT_ClientID)
    Catch ex As Exception
        <error handling code>
    End Try
    Return code
End Function

Public Sub MQTT_Publish(ByVal DeviceID As String, ByVal Channel As String, ByVal ChannelType As String, ByVal Value As String, ByVal Unit As String)
    Dim myTopic As String = "MyTopic"
    Dim myPayload As String = "My Payload"
    Dim msgId As UShort = myMQTTclient.Publish(myTopic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myPayload), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, False)
End Sub
```

As this stands it works 100% OK.  The coding may seem a bit odd, but the intent is as follows :

a) create an object 'myMQTTclient' at module level so it has scope throughout the module

b) run StartMQTT() - It can still see the object.

c) within main program call MQTT_Publish many times - I can still see the object

Now the issue is this... it all goes well until "www.myserv.com" fails DNS, then the underlying winsock code throws an exception.

So ... I'm thinking - no problem - just wrap the declaration in a try block or check that www.myserv.com exists before launching the declaration.

Ah, but you can't put code at module level, it has to be in a sub or function.

Hmmm... now I'm stumped.  There has to be a 'proper' way to do this, but I'll be darned if I can figure it out.

Anyone able to help ?

Comment: I'm confused. There is no Module here. Do you mean class level?

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to declare that type of resource where it is declared. You typically want to keep it open for the minimum amount of time possible. it can be achieved with a `Using` block, or `Try...Finally calling Dispose`.

Comment: Unless you must keep it open, then you should make `MyServer` implement `IDisposable`, and put instances of MyServer in a Using. Inside Dispose, you should dispose of anything disposable. I assume MqttClient is disposable in which case it should be disposed of.

Comment: `New MqttClient("www.myserv.com")` is evaluated when the `MyServer` instance/object is created: it is similar to if the assignment were put into the `MyServer` constructor. ***If*** `MqttClient` were to "checks the DNS" in its constructor and throws an exception then, this exception would be thrown during the time the "containing" `MyServer` object is created.

Comment: @user2864740 that's what I was getting at too. It should be constructed in `New MyServer()`, then disposed when done with.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I means Class level, not module.

Comment: The intent is that the object myMQTTclient persists during the life of the application as it needs to keep open a channel to a remote server.  If it timesout, then it throws an event upon which you are supposed to reestablish it.   So I get what you are saying about disposing of it as soon as I've finished with it, but that's not really until app exit.

Comment: I think I'm following your logic about adding code to the constructor for MqttClient to check if it can when it's being created, but the constructor is buried within a nuget package, so I'm going to have to mod the packaged code, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I'd follow the advice from @djv about declaring it just as you need it. To wrap that in a `Try... Catch` block you can do that in an Init method.

```
Public Class MyServer
    Implements IDisposable ' As per djv recommendation which I second...

    Private myMQQTclient As MqttClient

    Public Sub Init()
        Try
            myMQQTClient = New MqttClient("<your url>")
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Do whatever
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' more code and implement the Dispose method...
End Class
```

You can then go on and implement the IDisposble interface to ensure that you release the resources.

Comment: Handling exceptions in ctors is generally ugly, as are any operations that can fail :} If it were my code, I would 1) "create a MqttClient as needed", eg. on Publish, or; 2) have an explicit `Open` call required for `MyServer` that created the MqttClient. (They both have subtle flow differences; but then there is no 'exception in ctor' situation to deal with.)

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for the heads up, I've corrected the code to use an Init method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure if I have the right library. But I found this Nuget package: OpenNETCF.MQTT which seems to have the class you are using.

I would do it this way

```
Public Class MyServerClass
    Implements IDisposable

    Public myMQTTclient As MQTTClient

    'Private Sub Ruptela_Server(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '    ' <some code>
    '    StartMQTT()
    '    ' <some more code>
    '    ' MQTT_Publish(.....)
    'End Sub

    Public Sub New(brokerHostName As String)
        myMQTTclient = New MQTTClient(brokerHostName)
    End Sub

    Public Function StartMQTT()
        ' Establish a connection 
        Dim code As Byte
        Try
            code = myMQTTclient.Connect(MQTT_ClientID)
        Catch ex As Exception
            '<error handling code>
        End Try
        Return code
    End Function

    Public Sub MQTT_Publish(ByVal DeviceID As String, ByVal Channel As String, ByVal ChannelType As String, ByVal Value As String, ByVal Unit As String)
        Dim myTopic As String = "MyTopic"
        Dim myPayload As String = "My Payload"
        Dim msgId As UShort = myMQTTclient.Publish(myTopic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myPayload), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, False)
    End Sub

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                myMQTTclient.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

And now you can see the usage when IDisposable is implemented, in a `Using` block:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Using myserver As New MyServerClass("www.myserv.com")
            myserver.StartMQTT()
            myserver.MQTT_Publish(...)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

This makes it so your object is only in scope in the Using, and the object's Dispose method will automatically be called on `End Using`

I don't know what the base class was originally and why this was declared `Private Sub Ruptela_Server(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`. It seems like it was possibly a form? You should keep your server code separate from Form code if that was the case. I suppose you could paste the `Using` into your form load, but then you would be blocking your UI thread. The referenced library has Async support so it might be a good idea to leverage that if coming from a UI.

I've made many assumptions, so I'll stop to let you comment and see how close relevant my answer is.

Comment: Hi djv - and thanks for being so helpful on this one.

Comment: Yes, it's a winforms application.

You are close - I'm using M2Mqtt library, I'm guessing the one you mentioned is a fork of that.

I should mention that I probably oversimplified the base code above.  The UI spawns worker threads to handle the comms part and there are delegates which negotiate between them.  I realize that's not the optimum way to design a 'server', but this one needs to be able to display messages as they are in-flight.

Comment: It's the intention to exploit the Async functionality later.

So..  I tried the suggested code above and I thought I was about to make a breakthrough, but adding the constructor 
    Public Sub New(brokerHostName As String)
        myMQTTclient = New MQTTClient(brokerHostName)    
        End Sub

breaks the build with 'Ruptela_Server is a class type and cannot be used as an expression'.  In the App.designer it references 

    Me.MainForm = Global.Ruptela_Server.Ruptela_Server

I also just want to check my understanding of your answer above WRT IDisposible.

Comment: (Sorry that didn't come out well)
The client needs to stay instantiated once connected.  It then maintains a channel to the server.  It then handles many, very short requests and is only intended to be unloaded (destroyed) once the app exits or we determine that the link has failed (on which case we re-instantiate it).

If I'm reading this right, your code above would aim to instantiate, create a connection, publish a message, then destroy itself.

I understand how that can be useful in other cases, but this would place a heavy connection load on the remote server.